# How to modify the colors of Ubuntu Panel?

Tags: panel, colors

The background of the menu of Ubuntu panel is white. How can I revert to it to black?

Here's a screenshot of the same:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that your theme is set to Radiance.

Click the cog on the top-right corner and go to System Settings > Appearance.

[image]

Change your theme to Ambiance.

[image]